# How can one automatically arrange the connections of a circuit with as few crossings as possible, given a set of edges?

Tags: functions, function-construction, graphs-and-networks, visualization

Here are two functions to create symbols of dc voltage source and a resistor.

```
resistor[{a1_, a2_}] := 
 Block[{d, l, res, s, t}, d = a2 - a1; l = Norm[d];
  s = a1*(1 - 2/5) + a2*(2/5); t = a1*(1 - 3/5) + a2*(3/5);
  res = Line[
    Table[{Norm[t - s]*(i/16), (1/(6*l))*Sin[i*(Pi/2)]}, {i, 0, 16}]];
  res = GeometricTransformation[res, 
    TranslationTransform[s]@*RotationTransform[ArcTan @@ d]];
  {Thick, Darker[Green], Line[{{a1, s}, {t, a2}}], res}]
dc[{a1_, a2_}] := Block[{d, l, res, s, t, r}, d = a2 - a1; l = Norm[d];
  s = a1*(1 - 2/5) + a2*(2/5); t = a1*(1 - 3/5) + a2*(3/5);
  r = Norm[s - t]/2;
  res = {Circle[{r, 0}, r], Line[{{2*(r/4), r/4}, {2*(r/4), -r/4}}], 
    Line[{{{r/3 + r, r/4}, {r/3 + r, -r/4}}, {{r/3 + r - r/4, 
        0}, {r/3 + r + r/4, 0}}}]};
  res = GeometricTransformation[res, 
    TranslationTransform[s]@*RotationTransform[ArcTan @@ d]];
  {Thick, Darker[Green], Line[{{a1, s}, {t, a2}}], res}]
```

Now assume that I have a circuit with 6 components, consisting of 2 voltage sources, V1 and V2, and 4 resistors. The edges represent connections between the terminals of the components, and their arrangement can vary. Here is an example of the circuit with one possible configuration of connections.

```
edges = {V1n <-> V2n, V1p <-> R1p, R1n <-> R3p, R1n <-> R2p, 
   R3n <-> R4p, R3n <-> V2p, R4n <-> V2n, R2n <-> V1n};
```

Now I aim to write a function to automatically arrange the components in the circuit for a given set of connections (where the connections between the terminals of the components can vary).

Here are several criteria for the circuit layout:

1. The voltage source `V1` should always be located on the left side and `V2` on the right side.
2. The output should be a circuit with as few crossings as possible (although some crossings may be unavoidable).

Given these conditions, I expect the output for the given connections mentioned above to resemble the image below or something similar. Note that the square-angled connections are not a requirement.

[image]

I attempted this before, but the output was not as I wanted. This doesn't come as a surprise, as I am not familiar with the best approach to solve the problem.

```
edges = {V1n <-> V2n, V1p <-> R1p, R1n <-> R3p, R1n <-> R2p, 
   R3n <-> R4p, R3n <-> V2p, R4n <-> V2n, R2n <-> V1n};
coords = GraphEmbedding[edges, "PlanarEmbedding"];
vertexToCoords[{v1_, 
    v2_}] := {Position[VertexList[edges], v1][[1, 1]], 
   Position[VertexList[edges], v2][[1, 1]]};
Graph[edges, 
 Prolog -> {resistor[coords[[vertexToCoords[{R1p, R1n}]]]], 
   resistor[coords[[vertexToCoords[{R2p, R2n}]]]], 
   resistor[coords[[vertexToCoords[{R3p, R3n}]]]], 
   resistor[coords[[vertexToCoords[{R4p, R4n}]]]], 
   dc[coords[[vertexToCoords[{V1p, V1n}]]]], 
   dc[coords[[vertexToCoords[{V1p, V1n}]]]], 
   dc[coords[[vertexToCoords[{V2p, V2n}]]]]}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding"]
```

[image]

Please be aware that the connections between the terminals of the components can vary, as determined by the given set of connections (the edges).